# How Can I Reuse A Bootable USB Drive

Tags: usb, bootable-media

Is is possible to format a USB drive with Debian on it and use it for Ubuntu? I've tried that before with different Linus distributions, but it ended up trying to boot into the old  bootable operating system and failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. When you prepare a USB drive for an operating system install, it's not permanent. If you follow the normal formatting steps, you can wipe it completely clean and specify a totally new file system of your choice.

It sounds like you didnt properly format the old Debian installation from the drive. If you're on Windows/Mac, give this utility a try:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to say that you have made a bootable Debian USB drive. And you want to know if you can delete Debian files and copy Ubuntu ones and boot up Ubuntu from that drive.

This may sometimes work. In fact we're talking about two distros that use the same bootloader (GRUB). But I do not understand why you are struggling with this, when the best way of doing this is to reformat the USB drive and put the new OS on it.

Whenever you want to make a bootable USB drive start by rewriting the partition table and formatting it. If you use some software to make the USB bootable, this should automatically prepare the drive, although I can come up with one example which doesn't: Unetbootin.